# VUE.js Pass data from data through a html form to methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a users data object which has a `name` and `personal income property`.

1. I want to calculate the user's `credit score` on using the `computed property`
2. Add the result to through a form.
3. Make a call to an API endpoint. 
   I could not get the user data from the computed property into my HTML
   I cannot get the data from the computed property.

**Javascript**

```
 var app = new Vue({
  el:'#content',
  data:{
      filledResponse:{
      "name":"",
      "personalIncome":"",
      "spouseIncome":""
      },

      users:[
      {
        "name": "Joe Doe",
        "personalIncome":"3400",
        "spouseIncome":"1200"
      },
      {
        "name": "Chris Bimpong",
        "personalIncome":"32400",
        "spouseIncome":"12200"
      }
      ],
      item: {"name":"What is that"}

      },
  methods:{
      submitForm(){
        const filledResponse = {
            "name":"",
            "personalIncome":"",
            "spouseIncome":""

        }

        let requestData ={
              "fullname": "",
              "score":""
          }

        this.prepRequestData(filledResponse, requestData, this.makeApiCall)
     },

      prepRequestData(requestData, callback){
            requestData["fullName"] = this.filledResponse.name;
            requestData["score"]= scored;

      }
  },
  computed:{
        scored: function(){
        result = parseInt(this.filledResponse["personalIncome"])/parseInt(this.filledResponse["spouseIncome"]**1.2);
        return Math.round(result).toFixed(2);
        }
  }
  }
  }
  );
```

**HTML**

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <div id="content">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="user in users">
      {{user.name }}
    </li>
  </ol>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <div v-for = "user in users">
              <label> Name: </label><input type="text" v-model="filledResponse["name"]"><br/>
              <label> Personal Income: </label><input type="text" v-model="filledResponse["personalIncome"]"><br/><hr>
              <label> Spouse Income: </label><input type="text" v-model="filledResponse["spouseIncome"]"><br/><hr>

              <!-- <h3>{{scored}}</h3> -->

        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="">
  </form>

  </div>
```

[Run Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emmaAkin/ddcb461q/)!

Comment: Where is your computed property?

Comment: Just added the computed property. I

Comment: You are accessing `this.user` in your JS, but `user` is never defined. Are you trying to send one user or the list of all users?